# What is the preferred way to handle singular global variables for a django project

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

I am creating a django website and there are a few global variables that should be configurable by the owner through the admin interface. Some examples of these variables are a path to a document (resume, portfolio, ...), email address, social media links... These variables are unique (only 1 resume, 1 link to instagram...). Creating a model specifically for them seems a bit overkill, because there will only ever be 1 entry in the table corresponding to that model.

I know there are a few apps that provide this type of functionality, but I was wondering how this can or should be done in vanilla django?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use one of those apps?

Comment: From a maintainability perspective I prefer to use as little 3rd party apps as possible. Also, this is mainly out of curiosity. This functionality seems so trivial to me, that I wonder why there is no obvious easy support for this in django.

Answer (score 0):

Global variable approach may not be a good idea IMHO. Just create a generic model which can accommodate different configurations.

```
class SiteSettings(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(_('Key'), max_length=255, choices=CHOICES_KEYS, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    value = models.CharField(_('Value'), max_length=255, default=CHOICE_VALUE_VAL, blank=True)
```

Comment: Why is it bad practice? The variables also don't really belong to any specific app in the project. So this would mean that I create an app, model, database table... just for a few variables?

Comment: From my understanding of the question, it is possible to change the variable via admin interface. How would you save and restore the variable if there is any change after a system/application restart? If variables are hard coded in django, a new deployment is needed for any new value?

Comment: Good point. If the values need to survive a restart and need to be editable via the admin interface, they will have to be stored in the database somehow, which means creating a model. But django doesn't provide something like this out of the box?

Comment: I dont think any such mechanism exist explicitly. But Django caching mechanism could be used with a persistent storage...like DB(needs some specific features), redis ...etc, i have not tried this trick though.